# Get the command line output of a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a main scirpt that run several other programms in some order (to avoid lauching them manually). Hence I use thread to call them.
The first one is a Windows application and I call it like that:

```
class NepThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call('PATH_TO_PRGM.exe')
        pass
#...
nepThread = NepThread()
nepThread.daemon = True
nepThread.start()
```

Then I run a Python script in kind of same way:

```
class UsbCameraThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(["python", 'PATH\\USBcamera.py'])
        pass
#...
usbCameraThread = UsbCameraThread()
usbCameraThread.daemon = True
usbCameraThread.start()
```

But for this one, I need to wait it is started before running the next script.
When USBcamera script is ready, it writes something on cout and then starts an infinite loop:

```
print('Start Video recording!')
while True:
```

My question is: how can I got the command line output to know if the script is started?

Thanks in advance!
Dark Patate

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `subprocess.Popen()` instruction to capture the stdout stream. Here is a sample of its usage:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen( command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
stdout_stream, stderr_stream = proc.communicate()
stdout_stream = stdout_stream.decode( "ascii" )
```

Then print out the contents of `stdout_stream`.

Comment: I tried with that in my thread instead of my code, but it's not running (no error, but nothing happened).

Comment: Perhaps the stream used was another instance of a stream, instead of the one already existing. Try using a temporary file to pipe the output, so by then, you have to read the content of the temporary file to determine if the script is started (remember to delete the temporary file after reading it).